# Host ASP.NET application locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-hosting

I have an ASP.NET web application (built in visual studio 2012) and would like to place it on my local network so I can access it on my mobile phone. I've never hosted an ASP.NET site before and really have no clue how.

I figured I could just access it using my IP and the port it uses on my localhost, but no luck.

How can I (very easily and quickly) stick my project online? Doesn't need to be accessible outside my network.

The project is built using Razor/ASP.NET/C# and SQL

Thanks

Comment: You should be able to access it using your IP and port number, provided that the phone is on the same network as the computer.  Is the application running when you try to access it?

Comment: Cassini, the development server which ships with VS does not allow external connections.  You need to set up IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to open up the port the site is running on. Go to Control Panel -> Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings. Click on Inbound Rules and Add a New Rule, select Port and run through the wizard, using the port number the site is assigned in IIS.

More details here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

You should be able to view it on your phone now by using your ip and port.

To run your site off IIS:

You'll need to first enabled IIS in Windows, you can use the link Humpy posted in his response.

Then once its enabled, open it up and expand the Sites folder, and then right click and Add a new site. Give it a name, point it to the directory your site is running off and assign it a port. Test it by going to locahost:{yourport}. You might have to set permissions by selecting your site, and then hitting the Edit Permissions link in IIS, select the security tab, hit Edit, then Add and use the application pool the site is running off, so IIS AppPool\{yoursite name}. Give it full permissions since its running locally and then hit the site again in the browser.

Comment: A lot of playing around and I got it set up! Thanks a lot dude

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows Vista or 7, you can set up IIS. [Here is a Link](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/installing-iis-on-windows-vista-and-windows-7) to help you out.
Not sure if this is what you were looking for but I think it is.